# Populating a 2 column table with data from a list<string>

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, list

I have an issue regarding a piece of code which populates a 2x* table. When the code runs the table gets created and displayed. This is how it should be. The issue is that the table is way down at the bottom of the page. I have to scroll for a good 5 seconds before i see it.

Here's the table creation/population:

```
string[] myDir = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

        List<HyperLink> hlist = new List<HyperLink>();

        foreach (string dir in myDir)
        {

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
            string currentDirectoryName = info.Name;

            HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
            hl.NavigateUrl = dir.ToString(); 
            hl.Text = currentDirectoryName.ToString();
            hlist.Add(hl);

            for (int i = 0; i < hlist.Count; i += 2)
            {
                TableRow row = new TableRow(); // Create the new rows
                Table1.Rows.Add(row);
                for (int j = i; j < Math.Min(i + 2, hlist.Count); j++)
                {
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    cell.CssClass = "RefItems";
                    cell.Controls.Add(hlist[j]);
                    row.Controls.Add(cell);
                }
            }

        }
```

Any Ideas as to why the table is so far down the screen? I think its something obvious because I've used this code in the past and it has worked fine. The HTML for the table is below:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server"></asp:Table>
            </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: check your refitems css, might be a typo setting in the margin or padding. Inspect the element with firebug.

Comment: if i get rid of ref items, its still the same. Its a weird one :(

Comment: I figured it out. My for statement for populating the table should of been outside my foreach statement. Thanks anyway!